# got this error in IF Condition

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here i'm going to register a user.Finally i wanted to check If registeration successful then needs to go next page..I got thie error in IF Condition

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AAZZZ;Initial Catalog=DRDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UserRegistration_SP", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", TextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", TextBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", TextBox9.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox10.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (Registration == Successful)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Registration2.aspx");
        }
        else {
            lblinfo.Text = "Some error has happend";
        }



    }
```

Comment: what is `Registration`? How is it declared?
i think the problem is NullReference

Comment: What are `Registration` and `Successful`?

Comment: i'm newbie to programming.. before that there was a Page load event.. can i declare it there ?

Comment: or declare it inside the button click event ?

Comment: atleast Tell Us What was the error you got ?

Comment: (Registration == Successful)
  have relation with previous query, or you want just compilation

Comment: error is EPSystem.Registration is a type but it used like a variable

Comment: Actually i wanted to If above registration success then need to go registration2.aspx page

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that you are doing and Insert or Update  and not sure what are the values for `Registration == Succesful` or how are you getting them

So check `if cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` does not `return -1` because `-1 means a rollback`

```
   con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (result != -1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Registration2.aspx");
    }
    else {
        lblinfo.Text = "Some error has happend";
    }
```

Comment: When i use int results..it shows me error on "Coloumn name or number of supplied values doesnt match table definitions"

Comment: Nimesh please check that the amount of paramters passed are same as the stored procedure, you are passing more or less parameters requried by stored procedure

Comment: i just change the int result = cmd.ExecutenonQuery(); then need to pass parameter from stored procedure ?

Comment: @NimeshPerera you to set you parameters first exactly the same as your database stored procedure (check spellings too) and then call cmd.ExceuteNonQuery. Look at this example here http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/05/sqlcommand-executenonquery-example-c-vb.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to determine if the SQL query processed/affected any rows?

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AAZZZ;Initial Catalog=DRDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UserRegistration_SP", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", TextBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", TextBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", TextBox7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", TextBox8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", TextBox9.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox10.Text);

    con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (result > 0) // I assume you want rows to be affected
    {
        Response.Redirect("Registration2.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblinfo.Text = "Some error has happend";
    }
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) - "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."

Comment: When i use int results..it shows me error on "Coloumn name or number of supplied values doesnt match table definitions"

Comment: That's an issue with the `Parameters` you're setting or your stored procedure not matching the database schema. It is not an issue with the if-statement. It's a different issue all together. The change above fixes your original question.

Comment: Before i added if condition it works... When i add if condition then it's not working... Now did your changes.. then i got above error..is there anything need to chage in stored procedure after your code updated ?

Comment: @NimeshPerera it does not it does not works it is rolling back silently. The only way to find out will be check yoru table if the records was created or updated